# tc u32 match protocol [any] in recent kernels -- where to discuss?

Tags: traffic-shaping, tc

I've been using debian with 2.6.26 kernel; now I've started to test 2.6.32 for my needs. And I've noticed that u32 filter behaves differently for, namely, "`protocol 802.1q`".

To discover the tendency, I've run my tests on ubuntu server with 3.0.0-12 kernel. And I've found that I can not match packets by VLAN id at all:

```
# this worked in 2.6.26:
/sbin/tc filter add dev world0 parent 1:0 prio 100 protocol 802.1q \
        u32 match u16 0x0ed8 0x0fff at -4 \
        flowid 1:fe51
```

So, that's the preface.

I would like to ask where is the best place to discuss these questions? -- it seems that [LARTC](http://lartc.org/) list is rather inactive. I am not a programmer, so I hardly believe that I should dive into [LKML](https://lkml.org/)...

Thank you!

## UPDATE

I've built 3.2.11 (latest stable) and in all my tests it appeared impossible to catch any protocol but `ip` (or `all`, which seems to be quite the same as `ip` now). But when catching `ip` or `any` it appeared impossible to match vlan tag or the like, with negative `at` value, too.

Comment: I see there's a vote-to-close here.  I would argue that this is a great question, because it's someone actually trying to solve problems on their own!  Also, selfishly, I'm interested in the answer, because there's nothing like a "linux kernel" stackexchange site, and as brownian says the LKML mailing list isn't really a great place to start.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting this into two questions.  One for here, with more details on this particular kernel behavior - provide some sample output from the filter, which would at least help others realize what the filter did before and why such a thing might be helpful, or whether this is a bug that should be reported.  Then a separate question on where to ask such questions, which you should ask on meta.serverfault.com or meta.stackexchange or somewhere like that, since that question is off-topic for this particular spot, I think.  Other possibilities are "superuser" and "unix/linux".

Comment: @nealmcb Thank you, I've followed your suggestion: http://serverfault.com/questions/370795/tc-u32-how-to-match-l2-protocols-in-recent-kernels